# Kafka: Is it possible for the same Key(string) to resolve to multiple partition in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We read the incoming records from our application and use user ID (as string) as Key for producer record when creating producer record in Kafka. There are thousands of user Id that the application handles per day.

What we noticed was the records having the same key (Z132384910042467345-0) were sent to the same partition (partition 2) most of the times but sometimes getting sent to partition 1 and 0. Is this possible in Kafka given that we do not use a CustomPartitioner ? I looked at the source code and they do hashing of key % partition count to arrive at the partition but can't figure out why the same key is mapped to different partitions.

P.S: Also looked at the source data (containing user IDs) for any anomaly but could not find anything.

```
if (partitionKey != null && partitionKey.length() > 0){
        kafkaProps = kafkaConfigService.getProps(kafkaConfigService.getKafkaMode());
        record = new ProducerRecord(topicName, partitionKey, data);
    } else {
        LOG.error("partitionKey is null. Choosing a random partition");
        kafkaProps = kafkaConfigService.getProps(kafkaConfigService.getKafkaMode());
        record = new ProducerRecord(topicName, data);
    }
```

Comment: This should not happen. The mapping of key to partition remains consistent. Did u dynamically add any partitions?

Comment: @IndraneelBende No. I did not.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add the complete snippet of code above? How do u get the partition key? What is data? Is it a String representation of a java object or something else? What is kafkaProps in the above example?

Comment: 1) if you receive key from external systems, check whether your key is sanitized for spaces etc.
2) if you can afford, log the key, partitionId and total number of partitions. This could help you to validate whether total number of partitions remained the same

Comment: Even if some partitions become unavailable for some reason momentarily, the hashing doesn’t change. So, has to be a code problem rather than a kafka problem.

Comment: @IndraneelBende I am facing the same issue (same key getting mapped to different partitions) and I have dynamically added the partitions. What can be the issue?